# How to set google map zoom level as it is which was selected by user when return back from another activity

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming

I getting issue in refreshing map .I want to stop google map from refreshing when return back from another activity.

I am using shared preference for storing zooming calculation but it not working .

So if anybody have idea about that then please revert.

listener i am using for catching zooming calculation

```
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {

            // if (position.zoom != currentZoom) {
            currentZoom = position.zoom; // here you get zoom level
            Log.v("Getting Zoom level", String.valueOf(currentZoom));

            getzoomvalue = currentZoom;
            savePreferences("Zoom_value", getzoomvalue);
            // SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            // .getDefaultSharedPreferences(CurrentLocation.this);
            // float getcurrentZoom =
            // sharedPreferences.getFloat("Zoom_value", 3);
             Toast.makeText(CurrentLocation.this,
             "Getting zooming" + String.valueOf(getcurrentZoom),
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // }
        }

    });
```

here is the handler which i am using for calling map
:

```
      Handler handler = new Handler()
   {
       @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        removeDialog(0);
        switch (msg.what) {
        case HttpPostThread.SUCCESS:
            String answer = (String) msg.obj;
            if (answer != null) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(answer);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            String liststr = jsonObj.getString(i);
                            JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(liststr);
                            String coopid = jsonobj.getString("coop_id");
                            String keynamestr = jsonobj
                                    .getString("key_name");
                            JSONObject keynameobj = new JSONObject(
                                    keynamestr);
                            String lat = jsonparser(keynameobj, "lattitude");
                            String lang = jsonparser(keynameobj,
                                    "longitude");
                            String status = jsonparser(keynameobj, "status");
                            String lastupdate = "Last Updated :"
                                    + jsonparser(keynameobj, "last_update")
                                    + "^" + coopid + "^" + lat + "^" + lang
                                    + "";
                            String roadtype = jsonparser(keynameobj,
                                    "road_type");
                            String state = jsonparser(keynameobj, "state");
                            String roadno = jsonparser(keynameobj,
                                    "road_number");
                            String roaddir = jsonparser(keynameobj,
                                    "road_direction");
                            String direction = null;
                            if (roaddir.equalsIgnoreCase("E"))
                                direction = "East";
                            if (roaddir.equalsIgnoreCase("W"))
                                direction = "West";
                            if (roaddir.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
                                direction = "North";
                            if (roaddir.equalsIgnoreCase("S"))
                                direction = "South";
                            if (roaddir.equalsIgnoreCase("NS"))
                                direction = "North & South";
                            if (roaddir.equalsIgnoreCase("EW"))
                                direction = "East & West";
                            String title = roadtype + "-" + roadno + " "
                                    + direction + "," + state;
                            double dest_la = Double.parseDouble(lat);
                            double dest_lon = Double.parseDouble(lang);
                            Location locationA = new Location("point A");
                            locationA.setLatitude(dest_lat);
                            locationA.setLongitude(dest_long);
                            Location locationB = new Location("point B");
                            locationB.setLatitude(dest_la);
                            locationB.setLongitude(dest_lon);
                            int distance = (int) locationA
                                    .distanceTo(locationB);
                            if (distance < 10) {
                                flagstatus = true;
                                flaglastupdate = lastupdate;
                                flagsnipst = title;
                            }

                            Location_onMap = new LatLng(dest_la, dest_lon);

                            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                    .target(Location_onMap).zoom(zoomvalue)
                                    .build();

                            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory


                     SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                    PreferenceManager
                     .getDefaultSharedPreferences(CurrentLocation.this);
                     float Zooming_value =
                     sharedPreferences.getFloat("Zoom_value", 0);




                    Location_onMap = new LatLng(dest_lat, dest_long);
                    addMarkersToMap(Location_onMap, "77",
                            String.valueOf(dest_lat),
                            String.valueOf(dest_long));
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(Location_onMap).zoom(getcurrentZoom)
                            .build();
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                            .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                    if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing())
                        dialog.dismiss();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            break;

        case HttpPostThread.FAILURE:
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: i tried to set shared preference for storing zooming calculation but it not working .

Comment: Please read this article and then update your post according to it. I'm sorry, but with this much information I can't help you... http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: posting some of your code will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `onCameraChange` listener if you only use it to get the zoom level.

Instead, you can add the following to `onPause`:

```
// Get the zoom level
float zoom = mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;

// Save the zoom level so it can be restored
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putFloat("Zoom_value", zoom);
editor.commit();
```

You can get the zoom level from the shared preferences and restore it by using the following:

```
// Get the shared preferences
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

// Get the zoom level (change the 13f to the default zoom level that you want)
float zoom = sharedPreferences.getFloat("Zoom_value", 13f);

CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
    .target(Location_onMap)     
    .zoom(zoom)              
    .build();    

mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Comment: why u set zoom value 13f? @toad

Comment: @Kirti No particular reason; it is just a default value if the zoom level couldn't be found in the shared preferences.  I left a comment above that statement that says you can change the 13f to any value you wish to be the default.

Comment: where i called camera position on resume or somewhere else? @toadd